# Switch Navigator Two headers

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've build an app with a `BottomTabNavigator` and `createSwitchNavigator`.

If I declare my screen inside the `MainTabNavigator`, the top header of my screens work as intended, but as soon as I import my screens (for example my `HomeScreen`) I get a double header.

I've tried adding:

```
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
}
```

To my `StackNavigator`, but doesn't seem to have an effect.

I've tried looking at similar posted questions, but have not been set off into the right direction.

Is anyone else familiar with this problem and how to solve it?

[image: Double header]

**App JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator,createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppNavigator />;
    }
}
```

**App Navigator**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
  },
);
```

**MainTabNavigator**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/clubs/Home';
import DetailsScreen from '../screens/clubs/Details';

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    // title: ' Alpha',
    header: null,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#DD016B',
      inactiveTintColor: 'white',
      tabStyle: {
          width: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        },
      labelStyle:{
            color: 'white',
          },
    }
  },
);
```

**Home JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    AppRegistry,
    ListView, 
    View, 
    Text, 
    StyleSheet, 
    Image, 
    Button, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    TextInput, 
    ScrollView,
    Icon,
    FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation';

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        // title: ' Alpha',
        header: null,
    };
   ....... App content
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)

export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
}, 

{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainTabNavigator` file, try this:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, weird tho since I have tried this before!